# Cannot convert String[] to string When using String.split

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing, split

I have a variable inside of a **String**. Now I need to take that Variable from the string and split it so it only take that part and store it in a new variable so I can print just that variable. (I'm sorry if its a rough explanation I'm new and phrasing things is still tricky)

fisrtName is the users input

```
String FIRST_SENTENCE = " There once was a person named " + firstName + " who lived in a city called " + city + ". ";
```

//there are other strings and variables but this is basically the important part

```
String nameOne = FIRST_SENTENCE.split(firstName);
System.out.println(nameOne);
```

All I need is for the println to output (firstName) aka (userInput)

Comment: If you're trying to print `firstName`, why do you need `nameOne` as well?

Comment: Why do you can't use `System.out.println(firstName);`?

Comment: When you `split` on some delimiter (your "firstName"), then you don't get that delimiter, only the parts around it ("There ... named" and "who ... called ...")

Answer (score 3):

> split

returns an array and not String. You have to store the result of split inside an 
`Array`.

try this:

```
String[] nameOne = FIRST_SENTENCE.split(firstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have access to the `userInput`, You can simply use below code to print it.

> System.out.println(firstName);

If you need to get the `userInput` from the generated String, Use this method.

```
private String getFirstName(String firstSentence, String leftWord, String rightWord)
{
    return firstSentence.substring(firstSentence.indexOf(leftWord) + leftWord.length(), 
        firstSentence.indexOf(rightWord));
}

String nameOne = getFirstName(FIRST_SENTENCE, "named", "who");
System.out.println(nameOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to assign an `array` of `Strings` to `String`.

```
String nameOne = FIRST_SENTENCE.split(firstName); // Illegal
```

The `split` method the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression.
You can modify the code like this to make it legal:

```
String[] splits = FIRST_SENTENCE.split(firstName);
```

This will give you an array of `length 2` with two values like this: `[ There once was a person named ,  who lived in a city called <your city name here>. ]` Please note you are not going to get the value of `firstName` by doing this unnecessary split if you are planning to use that from split result. You already have a firstName handy, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] nameOne = FIRST_SENTENCE.split(firstName);
```

First of all split() method will always result in String[].
 By using split() method on firstname you would never be able to print firstname, what it does is it breaks the String around the first name, as a result, the output will be String[] of length 2 with values :

```
[ There once was a person named, who lived in a city called <city>. ]
```